# Titanium Studio tiapp info is not properly transfered into info.plist while adding iconfiles

Tags: iphone, ios7, icons, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Titanium Studio. All I want are some icons in my iphone app.

In my tiapp.xml is this section:

```
<ios>
<plist>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
<array>
<string>appicon.png</string>
<string>appicon@2x.png</string>
<string>appicon76.png</string>
<string>appicon76@2x.png</string>
<string>appicon72@2x.png</string>
<string>appicon72.png</string>
<string>appicon72@2x.png</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
</ios>
```

Somewhere in the file is also this:
    appicon.png

All necessary files are in a folder called iphone, 72 dpi png, exactly measured.

Although there are 8 icon entries in my tiapp, after I built the app the info.plist contains only these two icon file entries:

```
Item 0 string appicon.png
Item 1 string appicon@2x.png
```

And Xcode complains about the missing icons:
"Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for ipad of exactly 72 x 72 pixels in png format."

Obviously it does contain that file, together with all the other ones mentioned in the tiapp.

I tried to edit info.plist by hand, to no effect. I checked and checked upper and lower case, I even mad this icon files again but still no luck. How do I do this?

Last week I had a similar excercise, and after renaming everything to lowercase ("appicon...") it was accepted by Xcode 5.1. The only thing I changed are the icons, everything else is the same and xcode keeps me awake for days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it had something to do with image or name caching by Xcode. After I renamed all icon files into something that has not been used yet (app-icon72.png etc) Xcode validated without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

appicon.png file has to be located in /Resources/iphone/ project directory.

Also try using clean project option before building it.

Comment: It is, all my iconfiles are in /Resources/iphone/. When I build I throw away the previous build. It has an effect when I change something, like the annotation or the upper/lower case. Sometimes after that there are 5 icon file entries in the plist, sometimes two. But there is always the complaint that the 72 * 72 icon does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Add following icon files to `tiapp.xml`:

```
 <icon>appicon.png</icon>

 <icon>appicon-72.png</icon>

 <icon>appicon-120.png</icon>
```

Its working fine for me.